# Check if user is still within CLRegion after 30 seconds - 1 minute

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I'm currently sending local notifications to users when they enter regions. However, I don't want to notify them immediately because sometimes they will drive past these regions and don't want to be notified about them all of the time.

So whenever a user enters the region, didEnterRegion is called. I want to wait 30 seconds (or a configurable amount of time), then check if the user is still in the region (which I know how to do already) and if the user is still in that region, then notify the user.

Android has a way of doing this with a dwell property.

I know I can use dispatch_after(), but I can't gain the main thread back when the phone is asleep (or the app is suspended).

The phone will wake up automatically, by Apple's design, when a region is entered. When that happens, I want to wait for 30 seconds, then check again if user is still in location. Here's a code snippet that doesn't currently work:

```
// triggered when user enters monitored region.
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    // Wait 60 seconds and if user is still within region, try to send notification 
    delay(60){
        self.locationManager.requestStateForRegion(region)
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, forRegion region: CLRegion) {
    // only notify user if user is still within this region.
    if state == CLRegionState.Inside{
        if region is CLCircularRegion {
            handleRegionEvent(region)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this with region monitoring alone. You need something else to trigger your app in the background. You can start full location updates once you are in the region or you can use a server to send a silent push notification. You might also look at starting visit monitoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to do this:
when the app gets notified that the user has entered a region, it should schedule a local notification for 30 seconds after. You need to set an identifier in this notification.
Now, if nothing happens this notification will be delivered to the user.

What could happen that prevents this?
The user leaving the region.

So, when the app gets notified that the user has exited a region, it should look for a scheduled notification with some known identifier and remove it as it's no longer relevant.

Comment: I actually really like this idea. And it's probably better than what I ended up doing which is to request time from iOS to run a background process. Your idea is much simpler and probably more efficient. I'll keep this in mind. Thanks!